# Is-there an opposite of the `race` operator in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have two observables and I want listen to the one that emits its first value last, is there an operator for this ? Something like that :

```
let obs1 = Rx.Observable.timer(500,500);
let obs2 = Rx.Observable.timer(1000,1000); // I want the values from this one
let sloth = Rx.Observable.sloth(obs1,obs2);
```

where the `sloth` observable would emit the values from `obs2` as it is the one who emits its first value last.

If that's not the case, is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this possibility, for now, but I'm curious if someone find anything else :

```js
let obs1 = Rx.Observable.timer(500,500).map(i=>`cheetah ${i}`);
let obs2 = Rx.Observable.timer(1000,1000).map(i=>`sloth ${i}`);
let sloth = Rx.Observable.merge(
  obs1.take(1).mapTo(obs1),
  obs2.take(1).mapTo(obs2)
).takeLast(1).mergeAll()

sloth.subscribe(data=>console.log(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.3.0/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

**Edit** as pointed out by @user3743222 (very nice nickname :-D ), it would not work for hot observables, but this should be fine :

```js
let obs1 = Rx.Observable.timer(500,500).map(i=>`cheetah ${i}`).publish();
let obs2 = Rx.Observable.timer(1000,1000).map(i=>`sloth ${i}`).publish();
obs1.connect();
obs2.connect();
let sloth = Rx.Observable.merge(
  obs1.take(1).map((val)=>obs1.startWith(val)),
  obs2.take(1).map((val)=>obs2.startWith(val))
).takeLast(1).mergeAll();
    
sloth.subscribe(data=>console.log(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.3.0/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your solution (though I suspect you might never see the first emitted value if you have a hot stream - if the source is cold, all seems good). Can you make a `jsfiddle` to check that out? If you dont miss any value, your solution is the best. If you do, it might be possible to correct it by adding the skipped value back to the source (`obs1.take(1).map(val => obs1.startWith(val))`.

Otherwise, for a generic lengthy solution, the key here is that you have state, so you need also the `scan` operator. We tag the source with an index, and we keep a state which represents the indices of the sources which already have started. When all but one have started, we know the index of the one who hasnt, and we pick only the values from that one. Please note, that this should work independently of whether the sources are hot or cold as all is made in one pass, i,e, there is no multiple subscriptions.

```
Rx.Observable.merge(
  obs1.map(val => {val, sourceId: 1})
  obs2.map(val => {val, sourceId: 2})
  obsn.map(val => {val, sourceId: n})
).scan( 
(acc, valueStruct) => {
  acc.valueStruct = valueStruct
  acc.alreadyEmitted[valueStruct.sourceId - 1] = true
  if (acc.alreadyEmitted.filter(Boolean).length === n - 1) {
    acc.lastSourceId = 1 + acc.alreadyEmitted.findIndex(element => element === false)
  }
  return acc
}, {alreadyEmitted : new Array(n).fill(false), lastSourceId : 0, valueStruct: null}
)
.map (acc => acc.valueStruct.sourceId === acc.lastSourceId ? acc.valueStruct.val : null )
.filter(Boolean)
```

Maybe there is shorter, I dont know. I'll try to put that in a fiddle to see if it actually works, or if you do before let me know.

Comment: No fiddle, because I was just aking this by curiosity, but your answer seems interesting. I'll try that tomorrow. Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: I think I'll stick to my solution with the modifications you suggested for hot streams because it is much less verbose. I tried to make a snippet from your solution, but there was syntax error and I didn't want to dive into it. Thank you for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
let obs1 = Rx.Observable.timer(500,500);
let obs2 = Rx.Observable.timer(1000,1000);

let sloth = Rx.Observable.race(
    obs1.take(1).concat(obs2),
    obs2.take(1).concat(obs1)
).skip(1);
```

And as a function with multiple Observables support:

```
let sloth = (...observables) => 
    observables.length === 1 ?
        observables[0] :
    observables.length === 2 ?
        Rx.Observable.race(
            observables[0].take(1).concat(observables[1]),
            observables[1].take(1).concat(observables[0])
        ).skip(1) :
    observables.reduce((prev, current) => sloth(prev, current))[0];
```

Comment: what would you do if there were more than two observable ?

Comment: Sure, nice question!
Multiple observables would be something like this:
let sloth = (...observables) => 
 observables.length === 1 ? 
  observables[0] : 
 observables.length === 2 ? 
  Rx.Observable.race(
   observables[0].take(1).concat(observables[1]),
   observables[1].take(1).concat(observables[0])
  ).skip(1) : 
 observables.reduce((result, current) => 
  sloth(result, current), 
  Observable.of('immediate item is ignored')
 )[0];

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it using a combination of `merge` and `skipUntil`. The `pipe(last())` stops you receiving multiple results if both complete at the same time.

Try pasting the following into https://rxviz.com/:

```
const { timer, merge } = Rx;
const { mapTo, skipUntil, last } = RxOperators;

let obs1 = timer(500).pipe(mapTo('1'));
let obs2 = timer(1000).pipe(mapTo('2')); // I want the values from this one
let sloth = merge(
    obs1.pipe(skipUntil(obs2)),
    obs2.pipe(skipUntil(obs1))
).pipe(last())

sloth
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RxJS 6 and ReplaySubject:

```
function lastOf(...observables) {
  const replayable = observables
    .map(o => {
      let r = o.pipe(multicast(new ReplaySubject(1)));
      r.connect();
      return r;
    });
  const racing = replayable
    .map((v, i) => v.pipe(
      take(1),
      mapTo(i),
    ))
    ;
  return of(...racing).pipe(
    mergeAll(),
    reduce((_, val) => val),
    switchMap(i => replayable[i]),
  );
}
```

Use:

```
const fast = interval(500);
const medium = interval(1000);
const slow = interval(2000);

lastOf(fast, slow, medium).subscribe(console.log);
```